# Android how to call iptables from inside application

Tags: android, iptables

I can do

```
Runtime.getRuntime().exec("/system/bin/iptables --version");
```

And that does return the version number.

But when I try to manipulate `iptables` calls like

```
Runtime.getRuntime().exec("su -c /system/bin/iptables -A OUTPUT -d " + IP + " -j DROP)
```

Nothing happens.

I do it from a `adb` shell then the same command works.

Any ideas how to do this?

Comment: I highly doubt you can configure iptables from an App which doesn't have superuser permissions. That would enable any app to ruin user experience.

Answer (score 0):

figured it out, you need to root the emulator guys !